# Running a github repository for Node Js - configure env

Tags: node.js, git, github

I'm quite new at Node and Git, I've been working on this repository for a couple of days and I'm not sure how to make it work. It tells me to configure some `vars` but I don't quite understand how to. Which file should have the actual LOGIN, PASSWORD, SLACK, etc.(Or should I just type them in the terminal)? What should I be typing in the Node Terminal?

Neither am I sure how to run the github files since every time I call it in the terminal it types "No local config found" or "Cannot find module"

I have no clue how to go on, so any help would be REALLY appreciated.

https://github.com/nicolsc/slack-sigfox-last-message

Answer (score 0):

Create a file config.local.js and store the parameters inside. each existing parameter will override the defaults.

the files named config.*.local are also added to .gitignore which self-explain that those kind of files are configuration files.

Comment: Would you mind making a sample? (Like, replace this for or that) I'm not even sure how to create files. Also, wouldn't that make anyone watching the source get the actual passwords?